# Display odd and even numbers in table after a condition

Tags: php, html, wordpress

From my previous question I understood how to display a particular content in a loop in list and after a condition is met it should display in a div.

This is the code :

```
function the_meta() {
    if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
        echo "<ul class='post-meta'>\n";
        $i = 0;
        foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
            $keyt = trim($key);
            if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
                continue;

            $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
            $value = implode($values,', ');
            if (++$i == 8)
                echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<div><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</div>\n", $key, $value);
            else
                echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li id='slots_".$key."'><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}
```

Now I want to display the `$i` values after 8 in table in a condition that the even values after 8 in a td and odd `$i` in separate td in same table. Will something like this help?

```
if (++$i > 8 AND ++$i%2==0  )
```

I have tried this but was not working.

Comment: Try with out the second ++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
++$i;
if ($i>8 && $i%2==0)
{
  // do your work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (++$i > 8 && $i%2==0  ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use && instead of AND and it may work